# Gtk3: Dynamically adding to and removing a button from an EventBox: Button won't receive mouse press signals

Tags: python, gtk, gtk3, pygobject

I'm using python and PyGObjects (the introspection lib) for Gtk 3 here.

Consider the following code:

```
from gi.repository import Gtk

class InternalWidget(Gtk.Button):
    def __init__(self):
        super(InternalWidget, self).__init__()
        self.set_size_request(100,100)
        self.connect("button-press-event", self.on_press)

    def on_press(self, *args):
        print "The Internal Widget was clicked."


class ExternalEventBox(Gtk.EventBox):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ExternalEventBox, self).__init__()
        self.fixed = Gtk.Fixed()
        self.add(self.fixed)
        self.internal_widget = InternalWidget()
        self.set_size_request(200, 200)
        self.connect("button-press-event", self.on_press)
        self.connect("enter-notify-event", self.on_enter)
        self.connect("leave-notify-event", self.on_leave)

    def on_enter(self, *args):
        self.fixed.put(self.internal_widget, 50,50)
        self.show_all()

    def on_leave(self, *args):
        self.fixed.remove(self.internal_widget)

    def on_press(self,*args):
        print "The External Event Box was clicked."

w = Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.TOPLEVEL)
w.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
w.add(ExternalEventBox())
w.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

Above, whenever the mouse enters the `ExternalEventBox`, a button (`InternalWidget`) is added to it as a child. When the mouse leaves the `ExternalEventBox`, the button is removed as a child of the `ExternalEventBox`.

Now, if you run the code (which you can), the button appears and disappears properly. However, clicking on the button, contrary to what is expected, only sends a signal to the containing `ExternalEventBox`, whereas the button receives no signal.

Interestingly, the expected behavior (clicking on the button actually clicks it) happens when the button, rather than being dynamically added and removed, is added once in the constructor of the event box, and never removed.

Is this a bug, or am I just missing something?

Edit: In a nutshell, I only get "The External Event Box was clicked.", but never "The Internal Widget was clicked.".

**Update**: I filed a [bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=695618).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the EventBox event window to be below it's children using .set_above_child(false)

Here's the docs for it: [GtkEventBox](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkEventBox.html#gtk-event-box-set-above-child)

> If the window is above, all events inside the event box will go to the event box. If the window is below, events in windows of child widgets will first got to that widget, and then to its parents.

Comment: That won't help: The child is automatically added above the EventBox by default. I've actually tried that before.